# VS Code - why are these lines highlighted and what does it mean?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Somehow I pressed a combination of keys on my Mac whilst in VS Code and now I have in the LEFT margin some highlighted rows:

[image]

What does it mean and how did I turn that on?
How can I turn it off again?

Comment: I presume you're using version control (git or whatever) and those are changed lines (blue = edited, green = added, red = removed). You can hover the mouse to inspect the exact changes. I have no idea of how to disable it, though.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Thanks for the quick response. I thought it might be that, but I've been using Git for a very long time with VS Code and never seen this before. Doesn't show up in other files I have edited, only this one, suddenly just now when I pressed some incorrect key combination.

Comment: Do you mean that mouse hover doesn't display additional information?

Comment: Correct, on hover nothing shows.

Comment: The GIt changes are further to the left - see line 32, the blue bar, that is the git changes.

Comment: Yes, that what I mean with "blue = edited". I suspect I misunderstood the question and you're actually referring to the brown rectangle. If you're using the default dark theme that's the colour used for e.g. search matches.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález OMG you got it! The search box was open with 8 empty spaces in it, so that was the match! ha ha, thanks man!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comment from @Alvaro Gonzales:

If you're using the default dark theme that's the colour used for e.g. search matches.

Your search in file is probably open (CTRL/CMD+F) with 8 spaces in it - so it is highlighting those matches!